# How to slow down transform and prevent shifting of element when hovered on?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to create a Marquee that slows down when hovered on.

I managed to get the "slowing down" sorted, but for some reason, the elements shift when hovered on.

I searched around and understand it probably has something to do with transform origin, but just can't figure out what.

- Expected behavior: elements do not shift, and gracefully slows down (if that makes sense).

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="track">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
        <div class="box" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style lang="scss">
    :root {
        --animationTiming: 100s;
    }

    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 100vw;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .track {
        position: absolute;
        white-space: nowrap;
        will-change: transform;
        animation: marquee var(--animationTiming) linear infinite;

        &:hover {
            --animationTiming: 120s;
            transition: cubic-bezier(0.47, 0, 0.745, 0.715);
            transition-duration: 3s;
            transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out 25ms;
            transform-origin: top right;
        }
    }

    @keyframes marquee {
        from {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
        to {
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
    }

    .content {
        display: flex;
    }

    .box {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: When I hover my cursor on the element, it doesn't seem to shift. In fact, it almost seems like the element is not responding when I hover over it. Is this your problem?

Comment: I would expect them to have to shift because they need to adjust to the new timing (think of what they would look like if you ran one fast one on top of one slow one)

Comment: @aplua hmm weird. It should shift and "jump" when you hover over it, that's the behaviour i'm seeing now.

Comment: @AHaworth i understand. However, what would be the best way to get it to "gracefully" slow down? I see many tutorials on pausing marquees on hover, but none on slowing down (at least based on my research)

Comment: I suspect you may have to allow a bit of JavaScript and maybe wait fir an iteration to finish because I don’t think timing would be accurate enough otherwise.